# Can I create the index for a query by using where clause in oracle

Tags: oracle

I am facing some issue during creation of index for below queries:

```
select * 
from table 
where date_col >= '1November 1995' 
  and (   regexp_like(col_name,'\s')
       or regexp_like(col_name,'\s')
      )
```

Can anyone please help?

Comment: Please check first before creating the index why do you use *twice* `regexp_like(col_name,'\s')` connected with `OR`  and your suspect `date` literal.

Comment: Sorry this typo in 2nd regexp_like(col_name,'^A(*)'') should be

Comment: Please **edit your question** to correct it. Also, if your problem relates to index creation please include the CREATE INDEX statement you're running, or otherwise provide with some indication of what the actual issue is. We can't run your code, so we only know what you tell us.

Answer (score 1):

Only if you told us *which* issues ...

---

Looks like `date_col` should be indexed; that's easy:

```
create index i1_tab_date on table_name (date_col);
```

I sincerely hope that `date_col`'s datatype is `DATE`; if so, don't compare it to strings as `'1November 1995'` is a string. Rewrite it to

```
where date_col >= date '1995-11-01'
```

---

Both of your regular expressions are just the same; was it a typo? Anyway, that part covers a **function-based index** (if that's what's bothering you). Though, you can't create it using regular expression directly:

```
SQL> create index i2_tab_name on table_name (regexp_like(col_name, '\s'));
create index i2_tab_name on table_name (regexp_like(col_name, '\s'))
                                        *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00904: "REGEXP_LIKE": invalid identifier
```

but, you can use `CASE` expression instead (`\s` is a *whitespace character*, so it can be checked with the `instr` function):

```
SQL> create index i2_tab_name on table_name
  2    (case when instr(col_name, ' ') > 0 then 1 end);

Index created.
```

You'd then use it as

```
where case when instr(col_name, ' ') > 0 then 1 end is not null
```

Comment: yes here is  some typo in 2nd expression should be ^A(*)'

Comment: I am able to create a index based on column but how can we use where clause in index ?

Comment: *"how can we use where clause in index"* We can't, that's not how indexes work. If you have a genuine requirement for such a thing then build an FBI over a user-defined function which returns NULL for the rows you don't want to index

Comment: _"how can we use where clause in index"_  You don't.  You simply create the index.  When a query is submitted for execution, the optimizer will determine if the index is useful, and if so it will utilize it in the execution plan.